# How can I prevent accessing my webpage outside my WIFI?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating a web page that, briefly, connects business-clients. I want this to happen only when the client is inside the business facility. What I thought is to check if the client is connected to the business WIFI by the SSID, but then I realized that if you create your own WIFI network with the same SSID you can bypass this web's check.
Then I tryied to do it with the MAC Address, but unfortunately I couldn't manage it due to security reasons. Can anybody help me finding a work around or hack?

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you provide more details? Typically your WiFi network is a local (internal) network, so a server running openly on that network is only accessible within that network, not from the internet in general. You typically have to take steps to make something accessible from outside the local network. (Specifically, you have to do port forwarding from the router that connects to the internet to the server within the network if you want to expose that server outside the local network.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mention it is not my business but others businesses. What I have is a QR per building and I want that code readable only if you are inside the business in order to access its private information.

Comment: Host the website inside the network, and don’t allow outside access.

Comment: But maybe I can follow what you said and make that QR code redirect to a business's local server which connects to my own server. Do you think it is a good idea?

Answer (score 4):

Either host the website on a server inside your local network or, if you have to host on the public Internet, restrict access to the public facing IP addresses of your network (with a firewall by preference, but web server configuration is also an option).

Note you'll have to take additional steps if you want to deny access to people with VPN access to the network.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I need. I can create a business's side local server which connects to my own webpage. So when someone scans the QR code, it connects to the local server (there I'll fix the main problem) and then the local server sends an API request to my own webpage and so on.